# responseJson not present when using sinon.fakeServer

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, sinon

I have code which receives an XHR object after making an AJAX request:

```
$.get('/url')
  .then(function(data) {
    var jsonData = data.responseJson;
    var responseText = data.responseText;
    /* ... */
  }).fail(err) {
    /* ... */
  });
```

When I use this on my live site, both `responseJson` and `responseText` are defined. But when I try to mock the server response using `sinon.fakeServer` there's no `responseJson` object:

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith("POST", "/url", function(request) {
  request.respond(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', JSON.stringify({
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
  }));
});

/* ... */

// Then in my code
$.get('/url')
  .then(function(data) {
    var jsonData = data.responseJson; //undefined
    var responseText = data.responseText; //defined
    /* ... */
  }).fail(err) {
    /* ... */
  });
```

How can I get sinon.js to create the correct `responseJson` object so that I can use `responseJson` in my code and still have my tests pass?

Comment: I've had the same problem trying to test error responses. It seems like on any 400-500 response code, `responseText` is always an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are responding with a 400 (Bad Request) from the fake server instead of a 200 (OK). Is that on purpose and do you have responseJson available when getting a Bad Request from a remote server?

If it wasn't 400 on purpose: just change your 400 to 200.

Comment: Yes, it's deliberate. I'm trying to make sure the correct thing happens on bad errors, and yes, the object is present during a real bad request.